# Change Font of TextField

Tags: reactjs, input, fonts, material-ui

I need to use a specific font for a `TextField` from `@material-ui`, Here is the `TextField` code:

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  className={classes.inputField}
  hintText="Level Data"
  floatingLabelText="MultiLine and FloatingLabel"
  multiline
  style={{width:"75%"}}
  rows={20}
/><br />
```

I am new to React and `@material-ui`, so all help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `multiline`, you can opt to target the `textarea`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  inputField: {
    "& textarea": {
      fontFamily: "monospace"
    }
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

---

But to be answer complete, if you are not using `multiline`, just target the `input` element

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  otherInputField: {
    "& input": {
      fontFamily: "monospace"
    }
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `inputProps` prop for `TextField` to pass props to the `input` component.

like so:

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{
    spellCheck: "false",
    style:{ fontFamily: "monospace" }
  }}
/>
```